# convert excel sheet which contain micros to pdf using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl, xlrd

I am having excel sheet which has micros(vba). I am trying to convert excel to PDF document. I am able to convert excel to PDF but its only working for non vba cells. The cells which has vba its populating as NaN or with the forumla of the cell.

I tired to use python library openpyxl,pandas as dataframe and reportlab to generate pdf document.

When I am trying to read excel which has vba its by default coming as NaN value or with the formula. If I am using pandas, I am getting NaN. If I am using openpyxl, I am getting formula.

Let me know anyone has a solution in python or some other library which help me to fetch data not the formula or nan.

my current code.

## Reading excel with only data getting NaN

```
workbook = load_workbook(OUTPUT_FOLDER+'/output.xlsm', data_only=True)
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Summary  Inputs')
ws_range = worksheet.iter_rows()
```

## Reading excel with micros

```
workbook = load_workbook(OUTPUT_FOLDER+'/output.xlsm', vba=True)
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Summary  Inputs')
ws_range = worksheet.iter_rows()
```

## populating data from excel to pdf document

```
pw = PDFWriter(OUTPUT_FOLDER+'/out.pdf')
            pw.setFont('Courier', 12)
            pw.setHeader('Sizer Report based on input')
            pw.setFooter('Automated Generated Report')


            in_line_total_chars=100
            longest_char_length=58
            for row in ws_range:
                try:    
                    string = ''

                    length_left_side=0
                    for cell in row:

                        left_adjust=0
                        if length_left_side==0:
                            length_left_side=len(cell.value)
                            left_adjust=longest_char_length-length_left_side+2
                        if cell.value is None:
                            string += ' ' * 11
                        else:
                            spaces=' '*left_adjust
                            string += str(cell.value)+spaces



                    pw.writeLine(' ')
                    pw.writeLine(string)
                except Exception as err:
                    logger.error(str(datetime.now())+' '+str(err))      

            pw.savePage()
            pw.close()
```

Comment: You're much better off passing the file to LibreOffice in headless mode to create the PDF.

Comment: LibreOffice not able to hold mircors, its throwing error. I have to use ms office only.